# Text color of MenuItem(System Tray)

Tags: java, menuitem, system-tray

I'm using System Tray and Menu Item to create a simple JFrame/tray application, and I was trying to colorize some of the menu item texts, I searched and looked at the API's, but just couldn't find anything that allows me to do that.

Is it even possible? If not, are there any available options for me to achieve this?